# Tomcat with JAX-RS: default application class not working

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs

So I am deploying a JAX-RS application on a docket container and I only need resources such as Paths and WebFilters to work which is normally possible since it worked fine till I had to switch from the javax version to jakarta.

The [documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.1.html#servlet) specify that if there is no subclass to `jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application` then you just need to specify the default application in the web.xml which I did:

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
         version="6.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The documentation also specify that there must be at least one resource so I made 2 simple test classes, one for each of the annotations I'll need to use:

- the first one is a test filter which should print "test" for every requests made:

```
import java.io.*;

import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

@WebFilter("/*")
public class testFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("init custom filter");
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

- the second one that should return a simple string and print "get" when I access the /test url:

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/test")
public class testGet {

    @GET
    public String get() {
        System.out.println("get");
        return "test";
    }
 }
```

but when accessing any url liked to this servlet the first request returns an error:

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application]
    jakarta.servlet.ServletException: No servlet class has been specified for servlet [jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:860)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

For some reason I can't find what is causing it since it should work without specifying anything else in the web.xml as the documentation explains and the console log properly the message printed from `init` in `testFilter`.

one last information that might be useful are the dependencies I have in my maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

So if anyone has any idea of what could be missing or incorrect please help ^^. Also If I say anything wrong please correct me since It might help me find out what I did wrong and if you need extra information feel free to ask

Comment: You need tomcat 10+ for this to work, upgrade tomcat. Also your web-app version needs to be 5 or higher, currently it still is set to 3 in your `web.xml`.

Comment: my docker container is running tomcat 10+:
Server version: Apache Tomcat/10.1.10
and the version in the web.xml I tried with versions 3.0, 5.0 and 6.0 all with the same results. but you are right that I should keep a later version for it @M.Deinum .

Comment: Your dependencies only include an API not an implementation of JAX-RS. Next your filter is also wrong as it breaks processig. In the `doFilter` you need to call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` else it will never go beyond the filter.

Comment: Your pom.xml is wrong. Tomcat doesn't provide JAX-RS out the box at all. It only provides Servlet (and JSP and EL and WebSocket and JASPIC). Either install JAX-RS via WAR or replace Tomcat by a real JEE server such as TomEE.